# Updating Multiple Model search for Elasticsearch 7.8.0 and Rails (Deprication of Types)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Looking for suggestion on how to update our multiple model search. We are currently getting a deprecation warning on Elasticsearch 7.8.0 and Rails 5.2.4.3.

```
warning: 299 Elasticsearch-7.8.0-757314695644ea9a1dc2fecd26d1a43856725e65 "[types removal] Specifying types in search requests is deprecated."
```

Currently we are executing our multiple model query

```
    @results = Elasticsearch::Model.search(
      search_query,
      [Employee, Building, Department]
    ).results
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.